# ClassNotFoundException for dependent jar file of a java WebProject

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jar, classnotfoundexception

I'm currently updating a legacy code, and below is the error occured.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RequestController] in context with path [/ngsf] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException
```

Now, `MyProject.jar` is the one im upgrading to use SMBJ due to limitation to SMB1 from jcifs. Built the jar via eclipse [ right-click project -> export -> JAR File]. After i exported the jar, i delete the old `MyProject.jar` in `WebProject` and pasted the new `MyProject.jar` (basically i've ovewritten the old for the new jar) and ran tomcat via eclipse run server. However, the exception occurred. `com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException` can be found inside `smbj-0.9.1.jar`.

I did a comparison, using the old jar (using jcifs). everything was good. but when i used the new jar, above exception occured. Basically, i just updated the `MyProject.jar`. there is no modification on `WebProject`.

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: First check jar file exported from eclipse has all the classes .

Comment: `SMBApiException.class` i located inside `smbj-0.9.1.jar`. does it have to be outside `lib/` and inside `com`? because both old and new `MyProject.jar` contains the same structure inside `MyProject.jar` (jcifs.jar is located inside lib/ for the old jar, smbj is also located inside lib/ for the new jar)

Comment: If there is a package, it should be inside the package. That is how jar file is created. All the jar files should be inside lib directory.

Comment: i see, yes `SMBApiException.class` does exist